# Spring MVC Schema giving SAXParseException

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc

When I try to add the `spring-mvc` schema in `dispatcher-servlet.xml`, I get the following error. I had copied the xml file from the spring example given in STS. I am using Spring 4.1.1. This problem only occurs when suing the `mvc` schema and not any other:

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 8; columnNumber: 116; Error:  cos-all-limited.1.2:  The minOccurs attribute of a model group with "all" compositor that is part of a pair that is the content type of a complex type definition must have the value one.  The value "0" is incorrect.
```

My file is:

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">
    <annotation-driven />
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/jsp/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>       
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.mj.cchp" />    
</beans:beans>
```

Comment: Error and Schema you have provided seems irrelevant. Are you sure?

Comment: @Keerthivasan Yes. This error only occurs when I include the mvc schema and not otherwise.

Comment: There may be problem with imported XSD schema files. Version conflicts.I think you need to provide the URL of appropriate version of XSDs in `schemaLocation` attribute. Please check it out

Comment: @Keerthivasan No, that is not necessary. If a version is not given, it automatically get the latest version. Also, I have tried giving the version and the same error occurs still.

Comment: Oh ok, thanks for letting me know. I'm also not sure of what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

There is no namespace as "resources". Use following tag,

```
 <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/"/>
```

To make this one work, please add mvc namespace as well

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans 
 xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
 ....
 xsi:schemaLocation="
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
 ......
```

Comment: Yes there is a `resources` element. Search for  the element here: http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd.
Putting a version number gave the same error.

Answer (score 0):

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.mj.cchp" /> 
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>          
</beans>
```

`InternalResourceViewResolver` is to resolve resources under protected folders such as  `WEB-INF`.

Try above. Make `beans` as the `default namespace`. Both should work, but this works for me with Spring-4.1.1

Comment: It is better schema without versions. Spring points to the latest version of the xsds. 
If the xsd not in the jars or jars are not in the class path this might happen.
So clean your project and run with latest jars.
OR sometimes spring might use another version rather than 4.1 (who knows).
Get the latest jars or if this is a maven project, remove spring jars and update again.